# Why isn't my HTC Hero upgrading?

Tags: htc-hero, 2.1-eclair, updates

Located in China I've been waiting forever for the HTC Hero update to Android 2.1. However now everywhere around the world people are getting it.

I do get the occasional update, and then I get prompted to reset the phone, however when I reset it the update does not get installed (missing update.zip on SD card?)

Or maybe I have to relocate to England? Could I fake this with a VPN/proxy? If so how could I set this up?

Cheers

Comment: Your best bet is rooting it, in which case your question would a duplicate of [mine](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-do-i-root-my-htc-hero). If it's locked, you can't install other WWE's, so root is the easiest way to go.

Comment: No I would really not like to root the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Does China have an extra Android version or do you have either the US version or the European version?

To let my own European Hero install Android 2.1 I had to tell it to manually check for new updates.

Comment: How do you tell it  "to manually check for new updates" Did you end up getting an update.zip on your SD card?

Comment: StartScreen/Menu Key/Settings/About Phone/Software Updates/Check now

I never saw an update.zip and I think that simply happened in the background.

Comment: I have android 1.5 so i get as far as StartScreen/Menu Key/Settings/About Phone ||||||||

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether your phone is locked and won't accept foreign updates, you may not have to root your phone, but you will have to unlock it by using the goldcard method.

Luckily [this website helps](http://www.roothtchero.co.uk/goldcard-2) you do it in a few simple steps:

Note: **these steps will NOT root your phone**.

Download: [klutsh's Goldcard Tool](http://www.filefactory.com/file/b1d16ag/n/GoldCardTool_exe)

- Format your SD card to FAT32 by going Settings > SD Card & Phone Storage > Unmount SD Card then Format SD Card
- Launch the goldcard tool as admin by Right click on App > Run as Admin
- Connect your phone to your PC and make sure USB debugging is enabled (Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging)
- Click get CID (Try clicking MMC0 if MMC1 fails)
- Click the link to open the goldcard generator, copy the CID from the tool into it. You will get an email.
- Enable USB Mass Storage on your phone.
- Click 'Refresh' in the app and select your micro SD card.
- Click 'Load goldcard.img' and select the file you received by email.
- Click 'Patch MMC'
- You now have a goldcard!
- Now you can downgrade using the [Generic RUU](http://www.filefactory.com/file/b1ah474/n/RUU_Hero_HTC_WWE_2.73.405.5_WWE_release_signed_NoDriver.exe).

After these steps you've changed your Android version to a generic one and you can use the generic update to get it to 2.1.

**Kudos to klutsh from MoDaCo and the person who made the site!**